# Besides address is there other limit on max nodes via RS485 Modbus-RTU

Tags: rs485, modbus

Since there is 1byte for nodes' address in Modbus frame, the limit should be around 256.But some say there is some limit on this scenario (RS485, Modbus-RTU) base on chips and wire.

> Chips support 32 nodes:SN75176,SN75276,SN75179,SN75180,MAX485,MAX488,MAX490
>
> Chips support 64 nodes: SN75LBC184
>
> Chips support 128 nodes:MAX487,MAX1487
>
> Chips support 256 nodes:MAX1482,MAX1483,MAX3080～MAX3089

Are there other limits on this?Like reserved addresses as routine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Address 0 is reserved as a "broadcast" address where the master can *write* to the slaves, however the slaves are not supposed to respond to broadcast requests. Technically the Modbus Spec only allows slave addresses 1 to 247 (246 total slaves).

> The address field of a message frame contains two characters (ASCII) or eight
>   bits (RTU). Valid slave device addresses are in the range of 0 – 247 decimal.
>   The individual slave devices are assigned addresses in the range of 1 – 247. A
>   master addresses a slave by placing the slave address in the address field of the
>   message. When the slave sends its response, it places its own address in this
>   address field of the response to let the master know which slave is responding.
>   Address 0 is used for the broadcast address, which all slave devices recognize.
>   When Modbus protocol is used on higher level networks, broadcasts may not be
>   allowed or may be replaced by other methods. For example, Modbus Plus uses a
>   shared global database that can be updated with each token rotation.

The rest is up to the hardware specification by the device vendor. A Modbus device that complies with the spec is supposed to be able to be a part of a network of up to 246 slaves, so you should only be seeing devices that support larger networks. In reality though, devices may choose to use smaller/more power efficient/cheaper chips that only support 32 slaves (or less). I've seen industrial devices that don't support more than 32 slaves on one RS-485 network.

If you want to read them, the [Modbus Implementation and Specifications](http://www.modbus.org/specs.php) are free on the internet. You should be aware though, speaking from an industrial equipment standpoint, there is "Modbus"-Modbus, and [Modicon Modbus](http://modbus.org/docs/PI_MBUS_300.pdf) (or Modbus+). The differences are minor, but worth mentioning.

By the way, you should separate RS-485/RS-422 from Modbus RTU/ASCII. Modbus uses RS-485 (or RS-422, RS-232, Ethernet, Fiber, etc) as the wire to transmit the protocol. Just because a chip is RS-485 doesn't mean that it was designed with Modbus uses in mind. For example, Profibus also uses RS-485 as a network with a 126 device limitation.

Comment: Just curious what happened to addresses 248 to 255?

Comment: @ShiheZhang I'm not sure about 248-254, but 255 is often used as the broadcast address (it is actually part of the spec). Broadcasting to 255 means "everybody on the network, here is a message" and slaves are not supposed to respond to broadcasts.